Moveit2: Action client not connected to action server: gantry_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
I am using ROS2 and MoveIt2 with an STM32 board to control a robot that has 3 motors for 3 joints. I have a launch file that loads the urdf of the robot and launches Moveit and i can see the robot in Rviz. I have an ros2 node that subscribes to /dispaly_planned_path coming from moveit to get the planned path, translate it into a type understandable by microROS to send to the stm32 node, and then the stm32 node publishes to joint_states to update the joint states to send to moveit.
when i plan a path in Rviz, i get that the path is planned successfully, but when I try to execute the path, it says that the path is failed.
I have a controller in the moveit_controllers.yaml file, and from what I understand, since i am not using ros2_control and this is a real robot and not a simulation, i do not need to actually spawn the controller in the launch file the same way i did with the gazebo simulation of the same robot. and the output of moveit shows that there is one controller in the list. Here is the output:
rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734467722.431408624] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group gantry
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734467722.431426890] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'gantry' in namespace ''
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734467722.441385918] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group gantry.
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734467722.441994733] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group gantry
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734467722.442356010] [interactive_marker_display_99133251532928]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734467722.474554478] [interactive_marker_display_99133251532928]: Service response received for initialization
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734468726.983857512] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468726.985489506] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468726.985890464] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734468726.985954879] [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468727.667148200] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468727.667291650] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'chomp'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468727.669202971] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'gantry' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1734468727.691667329] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: Joint acceleration limits are not defined. Using the default 1 rad/s^2. You can define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml.
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468727.713483334] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Motion plan was computed successfully.
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734468727.714640251] [move_group_interface]: Planning request complete!
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734468727.715422125] [move_group_interface]: time taken to generate plan: 0,0215894 seconds
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468729.904270687] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Received goal request
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468729.904489455] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution request received
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468729.904559144] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468729.904596119] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468729.904813462] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734468729.904764395] [move_group_interface]: Execute request accepted
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468730.496166869] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468730.496334661] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468730.496380632] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [ERROR] [1734468730.496573058] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Action client not connected to action server: gantry_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[move_group-2] [ERROR] [1734468730.496588962] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to send trajectory part 1 of 1 to controller gantry_controller
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468730.496603641] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status ABORTED ...
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1734468730.496717742] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution completed: ABORTED
[rviz2-11] [INFO] [1734468730.497636778] [move_group_interface]: Execute request aborted
[rviz2-11] [ERROR] [1734468730.498039182] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::execute() failed or timeout reached

and here is my moveit controllers:
# MoveIt uses this configuration for controller management
trajectory_execution:
  allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 2.0
  allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.5
  allowed_start_tolerance: 0.01
  execution_duration_monitoring: true

moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:
  controller_names:
    - gantry_controller

  gantry_controller:
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - rfixed
      - rRadTubeLongitudinal
      - rRadTubeLift1
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true

when i run the controllers list i do not get an output:
ros@ros:~/test_mig_ws$ ros2 control list_controllers
[INFO] [1734468984.758719026] [_ros2cli_152998]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[WARN] [1734468994.775455419] [_ros2cli_152998]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[INFO] [1734468994.777421383] [_ros2cli_152998]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...

but the follow joint trajectory is there:
ros@ros:~/test_mig_ws ros2 action list
/execute_trajectory
/gantry_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
/move_action

